# Runtime error when using graphql-codegen query inside different file

Tags: typescript, graphql

I have a project written in ReactJS, TypeScript, and GraphQL. I use graphql-codegen npm package to generate the types for GraphQL.

I have this code:

```js
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";

import { gql } from './__generated__/gql';

export const _POLL_SET = gql(`
query PollSet {
  sets {
    name
    polls {
      name
      questions {
        question_id
        intro_text
        outro_text
        options {
          option_id
          label
          valid
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
`);

function App() {
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(POLL_SET);

}

export default App;
```

The problem is that when I put the query into a file, just copy paste and adding named export and then using:

```js
import { POLL_SET } from './queries';
```

I got a runtime error:

```
Invariant Violation: Argument of [object Object] passed to parser was not a valid GraphQL DocumentNode. You may need to use 'graphql-tag' or another method to convert your operation into a document
    at new InvariantError2 (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/@apollo_client.js?v=1e4a2ee6:31:26)
    at invariant (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/@apollo_client.js?v=1e4a2ee6:42:11)
    at parser (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/@apollo_client.js?v=1e4a2ee6:16327:13)
    at verifyDocumentType (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/@apollo_client.js?v=1e4a2ee6:16371:19)
    at new InternalState2 (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/@apollo_client.js?v=1e4a2ee6:16416:5)
    at useInternalState (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/@apollo_client.js?v=1e4a2ee6:16388:24)
    at useQuery (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/@apollo_client.js?v=1e4a2ee6:16383:10)
    at App (http://localhost:5173/src/App.tsx?t=1680805881602:29:7)
    at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-QJV3R4PZ.js?v=1e4a2ee6:12171:26)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-QJV3R4PZ.js?v=1e4a2ee6:14921:21)
```

what's weird is that when I add the same call to gql in my App.tsx it works. It even works when I add:

```js
const _POLL_SET = false && gql(`
query PollSet {
  sets {
    name
    polls {
      name
      questions {
        question_id
        intro_text
        outro_text
        options {
          option_id
          label
          valid
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
`);
```

And the question is how can I keep all my queries in a separated file?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was my codegen.ts script:

```js
import { CodegenConfig } from '@graphql-codegen/cli';

import { GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT } from './config.node';

const config: CodegenConfig = {
    schema: GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT,
    documents: ['src/**/*.tsx'],
    generates: {
        './src/__generated__/': {
            preset: 'client',
            plugins: [],
            presetConfig: {
                gqlTagName: 'gql',
            }
        }
    },
    ignoreNoDocuments: true,
};

export default config;
```

I've created a file `queries.ts` and the generator was only looking into tsx files.

Adding:

```
    documents: ['src/**/*.tsx', 'src/**/*.ts'],
```

solved the issue. I keep this question just in case someone had a similar mistake. I was expecting a problem with my code, not with a generator.